10th Anniversary of Lifehacks SE!
In December Lifehacks SE is turning 10 years old. Congratulations on asking, answering, voting, and building this community for a whole decade!
Whenever a Stack Exchange site turns 10 we like to celebrate by encouraging users to reflect on their experiences here.
How did you first discover the site? Do you have a favorite question or answer that helped you solve a problem? Any funny anecdotes or other insights on your time here, that you would like to share? We want to hear it all!

What is the exact date of anniversary?

@MathGuy the site entered private beta on December 9, 2014, and public beta on December 22, 2014. Public beta is usually the date we consider when counting anniversaries.

Congratulations to Lifehacks on this milestone!
